# Routing Packets in a Wi-Fi network (802.11)

Tags: communication, wireless

Say we have a router (capable of 802.11 protocols) and some number of devices that are configured to communicate with this router. I have learnt about how devices/nodes use CSMA/CA to transmit data, and other mechanisms such as RTS/CTS & NAV, to help prevent collisions in the wireless medium.

However, I haven't been able to find an answer to a subtle issue. If one device intends to communicate with another device, then would it be possible for the devices to communicate directly with one another (assuming they are within each other's range)? Or would they still have to send packets via the router?

I just feel that a significant latency is introduced if the devices have data to send to each other, but have to still route packets through the router. The same CSMA/CA scheme could be used to coordinate transmissions between the devices directly.

Comment: When you ask "would it be possible for the devices to communicate directly with one another", do you mean "Does something in the current suite of 802.11 protocols support this" or "Is it possible to design a new protocol stack that could do this"?

Comment: I'm asking whether current 802.11 standard supports direct transmissions between devices on the same subnet.

Comment: 'subnet' is a TCP/IP term, but you're asking about 802.11, which is not restricted to only handling TCP/IP. 'subnets' are meaningless at the 802.11 level. Devices with the same TCP/IP subnet could be connected to different APs with different APNs and devices connected to the same AP with the same APN could have different subnets.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network

Comment: Oh I see. I have rephrased my question.

Comment: @Dampmaskin I was under the impression that WANETs and WLANs are different classes of wireless networks, each having their own protocol suite. I am aware that D2D communication occurs in WANETs.

Comment: Ok. My point was just that there are other protocols for that. I am personally not aware of any support for decentralized networks in 802.11 WLANs. What latencies are significant depends heavily on the use case, btw. For example, SONOS use a proprietary mesh network for their in-house audio streaming, because they felt that 802.11 didn't provide sufficiently low latency for synchronized playback, while Squeezebox using 802.11g managed to circumvent the whole limitation by constantly measuring the latency and compensating in software. Horses for courses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Wi-Fi Direct](http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~bivasm/uc_notes/wifi_direct_2.pdf), which allows devices to communicate to each other in a P2P manner, without any access points.

It facilitates connection between the devices over 802.11 protocols.

Latest revision of the specification can be accessed [here](https://www.wi-fi.org/downloads-registered-download/Wi-Fi%2BP2P%2BTechnical%2BSpecification%2Bv1.7.pdf) (it will redirect to the pdf)